# Solving java.lang.ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Can anyone help me solve this error please?

```
package bigdata.tp1;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path inputPath=new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputPath=new Path(args[1]);// ligne 16
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "wordcount");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,outputPath);
        if (!job.waitForCompletion(true))
            return;
    }

}
```

[image]

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index 1 out of bounds for length 1    at
>   bigdata.tp1.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:16)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're tying to access your second comandline parameter while only supplying one parameter.
Check the parameter count before accessing those.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the second argument to the program's arguments, which is: src / main / resources / output
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the second argument to the program's arguments, which is: src / main / resources / output.
So under Run-> Edit Settings ... → + → Application) I have to add under the Program Arguments **src/main/resources/output**

Answer (score 0):

If you expect 2 program arguments then you need to check them first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   if(args.length != 2){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exact 2 arguments needed");
   }
   //your code here
}
```